# Matlab: saving convex hull without displaying it

Tags: image, matlab, save, convex-hull

I used the convhull function to get the convex hull of my 3D image. I'd like to save it to few .png files, but without displaying it as a matlab figure.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
K = convhull(myPixelLis, 'simplify', true);
myConvexHull = zeros(size(image));
myConvexHull(K == 1) = 1;
for i =1:size(image, 3)
   imwrite(myConvexHull(:,:,i), ['path', num2str(i), '.png'],'.png');
end
```

The code doesn't work, because K isn't a list of pixel indexes. But how can properly I do it?

Comment: You can create the figure as invisible with `figure('Visible','off');`. Then plot the convex hull on the figure, and then save that figure to a file with `print -dpng filename`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. But I'd prefer to save the convex hull as a set of 2D images. It would let me  see both the data and the convex hull. I don't have this advantage in 3D.